# Spark rdd uses the collect method to generate an OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I need to iterate over rdd,take out data for processing and put it into listbuffer. When I use collect method,Error is as follows java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded . Otherwise,the listbuffer is empty.

This is my code:

```
val recoList = new ListBuffer[(String,String)]()
preUserProdcut.map(row =>(row._1,row._2))
  .foreach(row => {
    val recoItemList = new ListBuffer[String]()
    val userId = row._1
    val size = row._2.size
    for (i <- 0 to(size -1)){
      recoItemList.append(int2ItemIdMap.getOrElse(row._2(i).product,""))
    }
    recoList.append((RecoModelEnum.UserCF_fqd_01.modelId + "_" +userId.toString,recoItemList.mkString(",")))
    println("############" + recoList.size)  //1. here length is ok
  })

println("############" + recoList.size)     //2. this code doesn't be executed
```

When I use the collect method, the code works fine on the small data set

```
preUserProdcut.map(row =>(row._1,row._2))
  .collect()
  .foreach(row => {.........})
println("############" + recoList.size)     //here length is ok
```

However, when the large quantity of data, error code to run on the spark cluster, error is as follows: Java. Lang. OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit is exceeded.

I tried a few methods, as follows:

```
sparkConf.set("dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy","NEVER")
sparkConf.set("dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.enable","true")
sparkConf.set("spark.rdd.compress", "true")
```

Cache data and set up partitions does not work

```
preForUsersRdd.map(row =>(row._1,row._2)).persist().repartition(100).collect().foreach(row => {....})
```

Setting driver-memory and executor-memory also does not work

I know that the collect method adds data into the memory, which is prone to errors due to the large amount of data

How do I optimize my code, how do I use the collect method. The listbuffer is empty without the collect method. The memory is insufficient with the collect method

PreUserProduct as a result of sparkMllib. ALS. RecommendProductsForUsers returns,The resulting form is

```
[(Int, Array[Rating])] objects, where every tuple contains a userID and an array of rating objects which contains the same userId, recommended productID and     a "score" in the rating field.
```

So, I need to iterate, process, and get the format I want(useid,product1,product2,.....) by using foreach, listbuffer, collect, and so on.And then through sc. MakeRDD (listbuffer), get RDD, write redis for use

The collect method is to collect data into the driver, which is prone to errors

Comment: Hi, can you try: `.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)`?

Comment: Why do you need `collect`? It gathers all data on the driver node and should be avoided without previous filtering or reducing.

Comment: What are you trying to do in `.foreach(row => {.........})` ?

Comment: @ Krzysztof Atłasik,Amit.PreUserProdcut is not the data format I want, I want to process the data in preUserProdcut through foreach method, get the data I want, and then put it into listbuffer, and finally convert it into RDD through sc. MakeRDD (recoList), and write it to Redis for use.Without the collect method, the listbuffer(recoList) is empty

Comment: I added some notes in the above question, please have a look

Comment: @Pablo López Gallego,it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need to use a `ListBuffer`.

You should use `write` instead of `collect`.

Comment: I'm doing a list of recommended.Each user has a set of recommended products, I want to put RDD (useid, Array (productid)) after processing, get (userid, product1, product2,... ), then convert to RDD and write redis to use the recommended list, so I use listbuffer

Comment: I added some notes in the above question, please have a look